# Build my own scanf function

Tags: c, scanf, atoi

For academic purposes, I have to build my own atoi() and scanf() function.

The first one was pretty simple but I'm having trouble with the second one.

first one:

```
int String2Inteiro (char s[])
{
    int j;
    int i=0;
    for(j=0; s[j]!= 0; j++) 
    {

        i=i*10 + s[j] - '0';
    }

    return i;
}
```

Now in the second one I'm having some issues that I think that are related to the stop condition.
My first attempt was trying to stop after the cicle.

```
char dig;
int cont=0;

do
{
    dig=getchar();
    array[cont]=dig;
    cont++;
} while (dig!= '\n');
```

The second attempt was:

```
int counter=0;
char a;
char array[20];

while (a!='\n')
{
    a=getchar();
    vec[counter]=a;
    counter=counter+1;
}
```

I'm not sure if the enter is well represented or if i should had use '\13' (ASCII code of CR).

Thanks in advance,

André

Comment: You're testing whether the stop character has been reached AFTER adding it to the array.

Comment: Yes, the `'\n'` is correct. But which conversion specifier is this supposed to implement?

Comment: As a note, it's impossible to implement `scanf` (without using any of the `*scanf` family of functions) in a strictly conforming way. There's no way to get its push-back behaviour (`ungetc` should do it for exercise purposes, however).

Comment: Your first routine is hardly robust.  It will convert `"abc"` into a value because it doesn't check that it is converting digits; it doesn't protect against overflows; it doesn't handle positive or negative numbers (prefixed with `'+'` or `'-'`).

Comment: @mafso: how so?  What is there about the functionality of `scanf()` that cannot be implemented while fully conforming to the standard?  I'm assuming you're not referring to 'you cannot reliably implement it with the name `scanf()` because that is reserved by the standard'.

Comment: @mafso: you've elaborated on what is not possible mentioning '[`scanf()`'s] push-back behaviour'.  What is the problem there?  When does `scanf()` require more than one character of push-back, which is the only obvious restriction I'm aware of.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The push-back is exactly as if the pushed-back character has never been read. This has implications for `fseek` and `ftell` etc `ungetc` doesn't have. Cf. the [C89](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/d9.html#4-9-6-2) or C99 rationale on `fscanf`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61606/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-mafso).

Comment: @AndrePacheco Technically, the stop condition depends on the type being converted. For example, if the type is `int` using `%d`, then the stop condition is any character that is not a decimal digit (after accounting for a leading `'+'` or `'-'`). Could be a space, a letter, punctuation, a newline, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should break out of the loop as soon as you read the stop character, not after adding it to the array:

```
while (counter < sizeof(array)) { // Prevent buffer overflow
    a = getchar();
    if (a == '\n') {
        array[counter] = 0; // Add trailing null to input string
        break;
    }
    array[counter] = a;
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: It does exactly what i wanted. Although, when I exceed the sizeof(array), i was expecting the while cycle to terminate.

Comment: Why would you expect it to terminate without checking for it explicitly? Computers don't do anything unless you tell them to.